# Why is the click event on a map pin not working?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, bing-maps

I want to add a pin to a Bing map and when the user clicks the pin an info box should appear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          function BingMap(){
          var map = null;
          var pinInfobox = null;

          this.showMap = function(latitude, longitude){  

              var mapOptions = {
                      credentials: "mycredentials",
                      center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude),
                      mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial,
                      zoom: 18,
                      showScalebar: false
              }

              map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
              Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'click', function(event) {
                  var point = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(event.getX(), event.getY());
                  var loc = event.target.tryPixelToLocation(point); 
                  that.addNewMarker(loc.latitude, loc.longitude);
              });

          };

          this.addMarker = function(id, title, latitude, longitude){
              var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude);

              var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc); 

              pinInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(pin.getLocation(), 
                      {title: title, 
                       description: 'This pushpin is located at (0,0).', 
                       visible: false, 
                       offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0,15)});

              Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', function(event) {
                  pinInfobox.setOptions({ visible:true });
              });

              map.entities.push(pin);
              map.entities.push(pinInfobox);
          }; 
      }


      $(document).ready(function() {
            var map = new BingMap();  
            map.showMap(50.364302, 7.559795);

            map.addMarker("1", "title", 50.364302, 7.559795);
           });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body> 
      <div id='map_canvas' style="position:absolute; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I put the code into a class which I create an instance of and call the showMap and addMarker methods.
Unfortunatelly the event for showing the info box is not called.

This problem only occurs if I place the code inside the class method. The code on the following page works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508987.aspx

Do I somehow have to update the DOM or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the `Pushpin` `click` handler which shows the Infobox is not firing is because of errors in the `click` handler that you defined for the map:

```
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'click', function(event) {
              var point = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(event.getX(), event.getY());
              var loc = event.target.tryPixelToLocation(point); 
              that.addNewMarker(loc.latitude, loc.longitude);
          });
```

`event.target.tryPixelToLocation(point)` will crash because `event.target` refers to the `Pushpin` object, which does not have a `tryPixelToLocation()` function defined.  Also with the code you posted, `that.addNewMarker(loc.latitude, loc.longitude)` doesn't refer to anything that was previous defined so will crash as well.  Since the execution crashed at the map click, the event will not get propagated to the pushpin click handler, which is why you are not seeing the Infobox.  If you comment out the code above, you will see that the Infobox appears when you click on a pushpin.

You can use the developer tools in your browser to track down problems like these for the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I split my map project into content pages.

I solved it by attaching the events like so

```
    if (window.addEventListener) 
    { 
        window.addEventListener("load", BingMap, false); 
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) 
    {
     window.attachEvent("onload", BingMap);
    }
```